# presto SQL - Filter records if date column format is not matching yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: date, presto, trino, presto-jdbc

I need to get all the records from a table that has a date not matching with the format yyyy-MM-dd.

Here,  column ID is unique bigint column. start_date is of varchar datatype.

Sample input:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp_like:

```
select id, start_date
  from mytable
 where NOT regexp_like(start_date, '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
```

This will work for '11-12-200' and 'None'.

If you want to include NULL values as well, add additional condition:

```
 where (NOT regexp_like(start_date, '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'))
    OR start_date is null
```

More strict date regexp is `'^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$'`

This will restrict month to `01` .. `12` and day to `01` .. `31` and will not allow other characters before and after date( `^` and `$` anchors are used).

**One more simple and powerful method**

is to use `try_cast(col as date)` - it will return NULL if not possible to cast:

```
where try_cast(start_date as date) is not null
```

This will also restrict wrong dates like Feb 30 (2000-02-30)